# Unable to compile sample code from The C Programming Language 2nd , page 29

Tags: c

Unable to compile the code on page 29, The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition.

I changed '`getline`' to '`GetLine`' in the code to make it work.

What can we do to make the program compile without changing it?

How did the author compile the code?

Here is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define MAXLINE 1000    /* maximum input line size */

 int GetLine(char line[], int maxline);
 void copy(char to[], char from[]);

 /* print longest input line */
 main()
 {
     int len;            /* current line length */
     int max;            /* maximum length seen so far */
     char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
     char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

     max = 0;
     while ((len = GetLine(line, MAXLINE))> 0)
         if (len> max) {
             max = len;
             copy(longest, line);
         }
     if (max> 0)     /* there was a line */
         printf("%s", longest);
     return 0;
 }

 /* GetLine:  read a line into s, return length */
 int GetLine(char s[], int lim)
 {
     int c, i;

     for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) !=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
         s[i] = c;
     if (c == '\n') {
         s[i] = c;
         ++i;
     }
     s[i] = '\0';
     return i;
 }

 /* copy:  copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
 void copy(char to[], char from[])
 {
     int i;

     i = 0;
     while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
         ++i;
 }
```

Comment: `main()` has been obsolete since  . . .

Comment: "What can we do to make the program compile without changing it?" --> compile using only the standard C library and no extensions.  What C compiler are you using?  What options are selected?

Comment: "Unable to compile the code" -> post the error message received.

Comment: Oh, i think  i got the solution: After reading the preface of the book, I compiled the code without changing it with `cc -ansi`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `getline` in all-lowercase has since become an actual [POSIX C function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) so that name can't be used in a POSIX-compliant program that includes the `<std*` headers.

Your resolution of renaming it to `GetLine` evades this issue since C is case-sensitive.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what compiler did the author use when the book was written?

Comment: @LittlePony doesn't the book tell you that?

Comment: @WeatherVane On page 6, you will find '`cc hello.c`'. But it does not provide enough information.

Comment: @LittlePony what does the book's foreward and introduction and appendices tell you?

Comment: @WeatherVane: The book does not have a forward by that name. A scan of the Preface, Preface to the First Edition, Introduction, first section (Getting Started) of the first chapter, and first section (Introduction) of Appendix A (Reference Manual) do not reveal any specification of which compiler is used, other than a mention of Unix and ANSI C. The other appendices do not seem relevant, by title (Standard Library, Summary of Changes). Are you just guessing that some information would have been there? That does not seem helpful.

Comment: @WeatherVane From the book's preface, '...and Pave Kristol provided us with an ANSI C compiler for final testing'. That's it!

Comment: @EricPostpischil the OP asked which compiler was used in the book he was reading, and the book may have said that. That's just a guess.